# Evaluate expressions Generic C# evaluation conditions polymorphism

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism, eval

I am learning C# and I am not very sure how to program the following problem. I need to create a class which is able to evaluate an expression. For instance

- Checking if two objects/strings are equal to each other
- Comparing two numbers.

For objects and strings only the operations `==` and `!=` are allowed but for numbers the additional operations `>`, `<`, `>=` and `<=` are allowed.

Now I would like to know if the following implementation is possible in C#? I created a interface with a Constructor and a Execute function. The Constructor sets the variables and the Execute function is has to be override by the classes who inherent from it.

Note that my programming/syntax might be incorrect...

I have the following generic interface.

```
public class ICondition<T>
{
    private T lhs;
    private T rhs;
    private string mode;

    public void Condition(T lhs, string mode, T rhs)
    {
        this.lhs  = lhs;
        this.rhs  = rhs;
        this.mode = mode;
    }

    public bool Execute()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Let another class derive from this

```
public class Condition : Condition<string,object>
{      
    public override bool Execute()
    {
        switch(this.mode)
        {
            case "==":
                return lhs == rhs;
            case "!=":
                return lhs != rhs;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Mode '" + mode + "' does not exists");
        }
    }
}

public class Condition : Condition<uint16,uint32,uint64,int16,int32,int64,double,float>
{      
    public override bool Execute()
    {
        switch(this.mode)
        {
            case "==":
                return lhs == rhs;
            case "!=":
                return lhs != rhs;
            case ">=":
                return lhs >= rhs;
            case "<=":
                return lhs <= rhs;
            case ">":
                return lhs > rhs;
            case "<":
                return lhs < rhs;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Mode '" + mode + "' does not exists");       
        }
    }
}
```

Followingly I am able to call

```
Cond1 = Condition('test','==','test');
Cond2 = Condition(12,'>',13);
Cond3 = Condition(14,'<',13.6);
result1 = Cond1.Execute();
result2 = Cond2.Execute();
result3 = Cond3.Execute();
```

Comment: For objects and strings don't use == and != use the following:
string a = "hello";
string b = "world";
bool blnEquals = a.Equals(b);

http://forums.asp.net/t/1511559.aspx?What+is+the+difference+between+a+Equals+b+and+a+b+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise you to have something generic like this:

```
public interface ICondition
{
  bool IsTrue();
}

public class Condition<T> : ICondition
{
  T _param1;
  T _param2;
  Func<T,T,bool> _predicate;

  public Condition<T>(T param1, T param2, Func<T,T,bool> predicate)
  {
    _param1 = param1;
    _param2 = param2;
    _predicate = predicate;
  }

  public bool IsTrue(){ return _predicate(_param1,_param2);}
}

public static void Test()
{
  var x = 2;
  var y = 5;
  var foo = "foo";
  var bar = "bar";     
  var conditions = new List<ICondition>
  {
    new Condition(x,y, (x,y) => y % x == 0),
    new Condition(foo,bar, (f,b) => f.Length == b.Length)
  }

  foreach(var condition in conditions)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(condition.IsTrue());
  }
}
```